# Magento 1.9 problem call Helper

Tags: helper

My Config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>  <config>
      <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
     </modules>
     <global>
       <helpers>
          <mycompany_mymodule>
             <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Helper</class>
          </mycompany_mymodule>
       </helpers>
     </global>
   </config>
```

Path Helper

```
http\app\code\local\MyCompany\MyModule\Helper
```

File i want call

```
http\app\code\local\MyCompany\MyModule\Helper\Config.php
```

My Config.php Class

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Helper_Config {}
```

My Class inside Model call Helper

```
http\app\code\local\MyCompany\MyModule\Model\Form\FileName.php
```

The Call

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Form_Input {
public function initializes()
{    
$helper = Mage::helper('MyCompany_MyModule/Config');
 Mage::Log($helper);
 } }
```

The Error

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/MyCompany/MyModule/Helper/Config.php' for inclusion
```

My http\app\etc\modules\MyCompany_MyModule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config>
<modules>
    <MyCompany_MyModule>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </MyCompany_MyModule>
</modules> </config>
```

Comment: is compilation enabled?

Comment: yes it is enabled

Comment: Is your config.xml code for helper is like this `<global><helpers><mycompany_mymodule><class>MyCompany_MyModule_Helper</class></mycompany_mymodule></helpers></global>`

Comment: Ok then disable that and flush cache and try again.

Comment: you should try with Mage::helper('mymodule/config')

Comment: Ansar, yes have try, but nothing

Comment: @OrazioD'Arrigo, can you share with us the code of MyCompany_MyModule.xml  plz

Comment: have add up the code

Comment: Please share full module code.

Comment: Please check file permission is that accessible for web server user? the code is perfect I have just created with same code in my local working fine so maybe issue with web server user permission.

Comment: it is readable for all user

Comment: i have delete and recreate the file, if i call Data return same error

Comment: Are you calling that with this `Mage::helper('mycompany_mymodule/config');` same code? I mean text must be `'mycompany_mymodule/config`'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81269/discussion-between-kunj-and-orazio-darrigo).

Comment: ok solved, deleting the files and recreating them, it was a problem of reading the files I do not know because the first time it had not worked, the code was all right.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

you can load your custom helper `MyCompany_MyModule_Helper_Config` located in

> app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Helper/Config.php

```
$helper = Mage::helper('mycompany_mymodule/config');
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work: error
Failed opening 'Mage/Mycompany/Mymodule/Helper/Config.php'

Failed opening 'Mymodule.php' for inclusion

Answer (score 1):

Try after disabling compilation and flush cache confirm below code.

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <mycompany_mymodule>
            <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Helper</class>
        </mycompany_mymodule>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Also, need to confirm that Config.php file executable for web server user

you can call that by this `Mage::helper('mycompany_mymodule/config');`

Comment: Compilation: Disabled | 
Cache: Flush | 
Same Error: Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/MyCompany/MyModule/Helper/Config.php' for inclusion

Comment: @OrazioD'Arrigo, Please share your full extension. have you created module config file in `app/etc/modules/` folder like this `app/etc/modules/MyCompany_MyModule.xml`

Comment: have add up the module config

Comment: @OrazioD'Arrigo,  Are you calling that with this `Mage::helper('mycompany_mymodule/config');` same code? I mean text must be `'mycompany_mymodule/config'`

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename your helper from

   `app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Helper/Config.php`

   to

   `app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Helper/Data.php`
2. `app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Helper/Data.php`:

   ```
   <?php
   class MyCompany_MyModule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

       public function workMyHelper() {
           return "It works now !";
       }
   }
   ```
3. You call your helper function like this:

   ```
   Mage::helper('mycompany_mymodule')->workMyHelper();
   ```

Comment: The Data already exists, I wanted to create a specific file for the configurations.

Comment: just add `/config` after `mycompany_mymodule`  = `Mage::helper('mycompany_mymodule/config')->workMyHelper();` if it doesn't work try to update `config.php` to `myconfig.php` and you call it like this : `Mage::helper('mycompany_mymodule/myconfig')->workMyHelper();`

Comment: return same error if i use Data

Comment: Your module is well enabled ? `check in app/etc/modules/MyCompany_MyModule.xml`
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_MyModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyCompany_MyModule>
    </modules>
</config>`

Comment: Flush also the cache, clean the content of `var/cache` from your server